# What version of Gazebo will ROS Jade use?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just curious if this has been decided on!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201146/what-version-of-gazebo-will-ros-jade-use?/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2015-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This kind of information can be found in [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) (which has just been updated):

> Jade Turtle (May 2015 - May 2017)
>
> Required Support for:
>
> - Ubuntu Trusty (14.04)
> - Ubuntu Utopic (14.10)
> - Ubuntu Vivid (15.04)
>
> Minimum Requirements:
>
> - C++03
> - Python 2.7 (Python 3.3 not required, but testing against it is
>   recommended)
> - Lisp SBCL 1.1.14
> - CMake 2.8.12
> - Boost 1.54
>
> Exact or Series Requirements:
>
> - Ogre3D 1.8.x (Trusty)
> - Ogre3D 1.9.x (Other Systems)
> - Gazebo 5
> - PCL 1.7.x
> - OpenCV 2.4.x
>
> Buildsystem support:
>
> - catkin: build from source, release for binary packaging, wiki
>   documentation, continuous integration
> - rosbuild: build from source

Jade will support Gazebo 5.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2015-01-18**:
Thanks!!!!